# Integral hanging in mathematica and I do not know why

Tags: integration, mathematica

Mathematica will evaluate this integral:

$$
\int_1^x\frac{1}{(1+C_1(\eta)(-1+x))^3}dx
$$

but not this one:

$$
\int_1^x\frac{1}{(1+C_1(\eta)(-1+x)+C_2(\eta)(-1+x)^2)^3}dx
$$

I'm trying to solve this, and it is really holding me up. Any ideas why mathematica just hangs on trying to evaluate this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this type of question is on topic at [mathematica.se], but if it is you would probably get a better and/or faster answer there.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been you you add the syntax you used.

Changing notations
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\left(1+a (x-1)+b (x-1)^2\right)^3}$$ what I obtained on Wolfram Cloud for $$J=2 \left(a^2-4 b\right)^2\, I$$ is 
$$J=\frac{24 b^2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+2 b (x-1)}{\sqrt{4 b-a^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4
   b-a^2}}-\frac{\left(a^2-4 b\right) (a+2 b (x-1))}{\left(1+a (x-1)+b
   (x-1)^2\right)^2}+\frac{6 b (a+2 b (x-1))}{1+a (x-1)+b (x-1)^2}$$ and, if $b\to 0$,
$$I=-\frac{1}{2 a (1+a (x-1))^2}$$ which, I suppose, is what you obtained for the first antiderivative.